# When the Jacobian of unstable measure converges

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $T:X \to X$ be a hyperbolic map on the compact metric space $X$.  Hyperbolicity means that $T$ has local stable and unstable sets with uniform exponential bounds, which satisfy a local product property (e.g. subshift of finite type or Axiom A).
We say that $\mu$ has a local product structure if there is a positive continuous function $\varphi:X \to (0,\infty)$ such that the restriction is of the form $\mu=\varphi(\mu^{s} \times \mu^{u}).$

A Jacobian of the measure $\mu^{u}$ with respect to the dynamics $T_{u}$ is the measurable function $J_{\mu^{u}} T_{u}$ such that
$$
d\left(\left(T_{u}\right)_{*}\left(\mu^{u}\right)\right)(T_{u}(y))=\left(J_{\mu^{u}} T_{u}(y)\right)^{-1} d \mu^{u}(T(y)).
$$

$\textbf{Question:}$ Under what (minimum) assumptions $J_{\mu_{k}^{u}} T_{u}\to J_{\mu^{u}} T_{u}$ when $\mu_{k} \to \mu$ in weak* topology.

That is an equivalent to ask about $\varphi_{k} \to \varphi.$ Thanks in advance.